# Want to disable TenGbE to enable 1GbE Gbics in Cisco 4500

Tags: cisco, cisco-4500

This is my first post into Cisco Forum, however I'm used to check it for every question or problem I have.

I'm putting back in production a Cisco 4507R-E switch with two supervisors, and what I need si to enable all SFP ports of 1Gbit by giving up the four ten gigabit ports, which I don't need anymore for the new purpose.

I've read that to accomplish that i need to issue the next command on the global config

```
hw-module uplink select gigabitethernet
```

But the switch do no recognise the command:

```
MAT_SW1_PT2(config)#hw-module ?
  module  Specify a linecard slot for the hw-module command
  slot    Specify a linecard slot for the hw-module command

MAT_SW1_PT2(config)#hw-module
```

Here is my running-config:

```
MAT_SW1_PT2#sh module
Chassis Type : WS-C4507R-E

Power consumed by backplane : 40 Watts

Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.
---+-----+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------
 1    48  10/100/1000BaseT (RJ45)V, Cisco/IEEE   WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V  JAE14041TI2
 2    48  10/100/1000BaseT (RJ45)V, Cisco/IEEE   WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V  JAE14041TDM
 3     6  Sup II+10GE 10GE (X2), 1000BaseX (SFP) WS-X4013+10GE      JAE1345NFR6
 4     6  Sup II+10GE 10GE (X2), 1000BaseX (SFP) WS-X4013+10GE      JAE1342LA4P
 5    48  10/100/1000BaseT (RJ45)V, Cisco/IEEE   WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V  JAE14041TH1
 6    48  10/100/1000BaseT (RJ45)V, Cisco/IEEE   WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V  JAE14310J4A
 7    48  10/100/1000BaseT (RJ45)V, Cisco/IEEE   WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V  JAE151702VS

 M MAC addresses                    Hw  Fw           Sw               Status
--+--------------------------------+---+------------+----------------+---------
 1 8843.e16c.6410 to 8843.e16c.643f 4.1                               Ok
 2 8843.e16c.5ff0 to 8843.e16c.601f 4.1                               Ok
 3 8843.e141.6740 to 8843.e141.6745 1.8 12.2(31r)SGA 12.2(31)SGA8     Ok
 4 8843.e141.6746 to 8843.e141.674b 1.8 12.2(31r)SGA 12.2(31)SGA8     Ok
 5 8843.e16a.a9e0 to 8843.e16a.aa0f 4.1                               Ok
 6 d0d0.fd3c.80c0 to d0d0.fd3c.80ef 5.0                               Ok
 7 e05f.b9d0.40e0 to e05f.b9d0.410f 5.1                               Ok

Mod  Redundancy role     Operating mode      Redundancy status
----+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------
 3   Active Supervisor   SSO                 Active
 4   Standby Supervisor  SSO                 Standby hot

 MAT_SW1_PT2#sh running-config

....
 redundancy
 main-cpu
  auto-sync standard
 mode sso
no file verify auto

....


MAT_SW1_PT2#sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch Software (cat4500-IPBASE-M), Version 12.2(31)SGA8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2008 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 29-Jul-08 12:23 by tinhuang
Image text-base: 0x10000000, data-base: 0x114B25F4

ROM: 12.2(31r)SGA4
Pod Revision 16, Force Revision 34, Tie Revision 32
```

Any ideas?? Could be due old firmware?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: As far as I know, all you need to do is to use 1 Gb optics instead of 10 Gb optics. The interfaces will still be called `TenGigabit` rather than `Gigabit`. We use a lot of 4507R+E with Supervisor 7, and we just use the proper optics for the situation, but do not use any different configuration commands (other than QoS).

Comment: But now, the half of 1Gbit optics remain inactive, and on the other hand, i cannot force TenGigabit interfaces, work at 1000 Mbps full duplex.

Comment: You have asked several question, and received answers for them, but you have not accepted any answers. If your questions have been answered, you should accept the answers so that the questions don't keep popping up forever, looking for answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Sup II+10GE in redundant mode, you only have the first half of the ports on each supervisor. You can find that in the [documentation from Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/31sg/configuration/guide/conf/RPR.html):

> When you select TenGigabit Ethernet uplinks on WS-X4516-10GE and
>   WS-X4013+10GE Supervisor Engines in RPR or SSO mode, only
>   TenGigabitEthernet 1/1 and 2/1 interfaces are available. Similarly,
>   when you select Gigabit Ethernet uplinks, only GigabitEthernet 1/3,
>   1/4, 2/3, and 2/4 interfaces are available. When you select to use
>   both uplinks concurrently, TenGigabitEthernet 1/1 and 2/1 interfaces
>   and GigabitEthernet 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, and 2/4 interfaces are available.

You will not be able to use all 8 Gigabit ports with these supervisors. You would need to upgrade to a newer supervisor to make use of 8 Gigabit ports, such as the Supervisor 6-E/6L-E (with the TwinGig modules).

Keep in mind that your older WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V linecards will potentially have performance issues as they are limited to 6 Gbps throughput. Upgrading to a newer supervisor won't change that restriction, but it will increase the capabilities of your WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V linecards to some degree as well (4 queues to 8 queues, IPv6 support, etc).

Answer (score 0):

> But now, the half of 1Gbit optics remain inactive, and on the other
>   hand, i cannot force TenGigabit interfaces, work at 1000 Mbps full
>   duplex.

Based on you comment, I think I see what you mean. You can have a total of four supervisor interfaces. With a single supervisor card, those are all on the single card, but with dual supervisor cards, you split the total of four active interfaces between the two supervisor cards: the first two interfaces on each card are active, but the last two interfaces on each card are inactive.

This is because a supervisor card can only handle four interfaces, and only one supervisor at a time is active. It doesn't matter if the interfaces are used as SFP (1 Gbps) or SFP+ (10 Gbps); that is just the way it is. The idea is that you use the four interfaces as uplinks, and when you have dual supervisors, you want the uplinks split between the cards for failover.

Comment: I'm not an expert of cisco products, but as far I understant, the limitation of only be able to use the half of interfaces is because the backplane bus capacity: refer to: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15-1-2/XE_340/configuration/guide/config/sw_int.html section  Deploying 10-Gigabit Ethernet or Gigabit Ethernet Ports